# Need to use RAutomation.send_keys to send dash charcter to putty

Tags: ruby, putty, rautomation

I'm trying to automate some work I normally do in putty, but I'm having trouble sending some of the keys I would need to send.  I try to send the `-` and see the `~` appear.

For reference:

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32]
- rautomation (0.9.1, 0.6.3)

  ```
  require 'rautomation'

  # Run PuTTY program
  IO.popen("putty username@host")

  window = RAutomation::Window.new(:title => /putty/i)
  window.exist?
  => true

  window.send_keys("-")
  => [45]
  ```

UPDATE:
I'm beginning to think it has something to do with rautomation as I tried the below and was able to send `-`'s.

```
    require 'wind32ole'

    # Run PuTTY program
    IO.popen("putty username@host")

    @wsh = WIN32OLE.new('Wscript.Shell')

    def test()
      @wsh.AppActivate('PuTTY')
      @wsh.SendKeys('Ruby{TAB}on{TAB}Windows/ hello -')
    end

    test
```

UPDATE: I'm almost 100% sure it's RAutomation since I tried to send a `-` to firefox/notepad++ and nothing showed up, but was able to send `abcd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for these keys has been added, although if you get the code from ruby gems it probably won't have it yet as the update was done 5/5/2013 and last rubygems update was in April.  https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation/issues/64

Comment: Starting from RAutomation 0.9.2 you may use the gem too.